# Props Vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm currently working on a Vue project. This is the router code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const SeanceHeader = Vue.component('SeanceHeader', {
  render: (createElement) => {
    console.log('render header')
    return createElement('div', '')
  }
})

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/', redirect: to => {
      return '/undefined/'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/vel/:vendorSlug/',
    component: () => import('layouts/velLayout'),
    children: [
      { path: '',
        name: 'vel',
        component: () => import('pages/velSearch'),
      },
      { path: 'old',
      name: 'vel_old',
      component: () => import('pages/vel')
    }]
  },
]
```

I have a cart in velLayout, I want to give it to VelSearch page/component. (I know a similar question exist but here, it's an object from component to children).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well... You have object for example:

```
class Phone{
   name: String,
   number: Number,
}
```

and now when you press button you want send data. So you can use `query`:

`<router-link :to="{ name: 'vel', query:{ Phone: {name: 'Jhon', number: '123456789'}}}">BUTTON</router-link>`

And in `vel` component you can access them by `this.$route.query`.